# How do you tag people with a slack bot?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I built a bot for slack. It reads the message when a new user joins and I intend for it to post a message welcoming them: "Welcome @*user*! What are you building!?"

When it posts @*user* it doesn't seem as though the actual "tag" is working. Do I need to tag their user ID when I tag people with a bot instead of just using @*user*?

[image: fontebot tried tagging cristopher.bello but the tag didn't work]

Comment: I think in Slack-uage this thing is called "mention"

Answer (score 61):

The correct format is <@userID>

You will simply get the user ID from the event (in your screenshot, the [channel_join event](https://api.slack.com/events/message/channel_join))

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "subtype": "channel_join",
    "ts": "1358877458.000011",
    "user": "U2147483828",
    "text": "<@U2147483828|cal> has joined the channel"
}
```

**Update:**
(I have not checked the solution proposed in the edit)

In the new [Bolt SDK](https://api.slack.com/tools/bolt) you can tag user by using the brackets around the `@NameOfUser`.  So the example above could also be:

```json
{
    "type": "message",
    "subtype": "channel_join",
    "ts": "1358877458.000011",
    "user": "U214####",
    "text": "<@NameOfUser> has joined the channel"
}
```

You would need to parse the `@Name` out of the message of course.

Comment: You can get the user ID by going to the profile and selecting the 3 dots beside EditProfile

Comment: Nice answer. I simply add `<@USER_ID>` to slack plugin to mention a user in the message.

Comment: It is named as "copy member Id" under the 3 dots

Answer (score 8):

Can you try adding "parse"="full" and "link_names"=1 to parameters?
For a quick test, you can use their tester [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test)

Comment: When using the tester you recommended, it tagged the user even without "link_names=1". When I used "parse"="full" it didn't tag the user and left the ID. This leads me to believe it's something to do with the [node wrapper](https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client) I'm using.